# How to Prioritise Implicits for More than 2 cases

Tags: scala, design-patterns, types, functional-programming, implicit

I was recently introduced to the technique of prioritising implicits here:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62679523/13213262)

Now, I am trying to generalise this to cases where the number of implicits > 2.

From this answer here, it says I can do this by creating a hierarchy of traits: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544705/13213262)

Here is some code where I would like to prioritise implicits:

```
object Example extends App {

  sealed trait Serializer[T] {
    def serialize(seq: List[T]): String
  }

  implicit object StringSerializer extends Serializer[String] {
    def serialize(seq: List[String]): String = seq.toString()
  }

  implicit object IntSerializer extends Serializer[Int] {
    def serialize(seq: List[Int]): String = seq.toString()
  }

  implicit object FloatSerializer extends Serializer[Float] {
    def serialize(seq: List[Float]): String = seq.toString()
  }

  case class Marker[T: Serializer](lst: Option[List[T]] = None)
  
  Marker() // ambiguous implicit values: here...
}
```

How could I impose the implicit priority of Float > Int > String in this case?

My attempt was as follows:

```
trait A {
    implicit object StringSerializer extends Serializer[String] {
      def serialize(seq: List[String]): String = seq.toString
    }
  }
  
  trait B extends A {
    implicit object IntSerializer extends Serializer[Int] {
      def serialize(seq: List[Int]): String = seq.toString
    }
  }

  trait C extends B {
    implicit object FloatSerializer extends Serializer[Float] {
      def serialize(seq: List[Float]): String = seq.toString
    }
  }
```

But this didn't work. Looking at the code I can see I am not doing it properly but I am unsure how to proceed.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can do

```
val c = new C {}
import c._

Marker() //compiles
```

or

```
object c extends C
import c._

Marker() //compiles
```

Or make `C` an object rather than trait

```
object C extends B {
  implicit object FloatSerializer extends Serializer[Float] {
    def serialize(seq: List[Float]): Value = ???
  }
}

import C._

Marker() //compiles
```

If you make `C` an object and rename it to `Serializer` (so `C` became the companion object of trait `Serializer`) then you'll not have to make the import

```
object Serializer extends B {
  implicit object FloatSerializer extends Serializer[Float] {
    def serialize(seq: List[Float]): Value = ???
  }
}

Marker() //compiles
```

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html)

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro, so a single object at the end of the trait chain can make the entire priority work - this is super useful!

Comment: @finite_diffidence Yes. For example in Cats here are objects extending traits https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala-2.13+/cats/instances/package.scala And you make imports like `import cats.instances.option._`